# Cross product of two polar vectors or two pseudo vectors

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors

I have come across to the statement that the cross product of two polar vectors or two pseudo vectors is a pseudo vector, but the cross product between a pseudo vector and a polar vector is a polar vector. What is the proof of this statement?

Comment: have you tried to work it out from the definition?

Comment: I assumed A and B to be two pseudo vectors and their cross product be represented by C. Then taking the parity operation on both sides, I proved it. But I am not sure whether the parity operator is distributive under cross products. i.e. I am not sure if I can write, P(A X B) = P(A) X P(B).  [P is the parity operator]. Is this proof okay? If yes, then please explain how P is distributive over the cross-product.